# Why is MySQL dropping my foreign key actions?

Tags: mysql, windows, windows-server-2000, mysql5

Cross posted from Stack Overflow, since this is probably more of a server admin type of issue:

Running MySQL v'5.1.12-beta-community-nt' on Windows 2k server.

I have a group of 5 tables (a,b,c,d,e) where 'b' has a foreign key to 'a' with the action "on delete cascade" c has a FK to b with the same action, and on down the line.

All tables are InnoDB.

On server restart the FK actions are getting dropped. Not the FKs themselves, just the "on delete" action. so I still have the FK constraint but no longer have any on delete action causing errors when I try to delete as it would orphan children.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The first GA version of MySQL 5.1 was 5.1.30.

You are using 5.1.12-beta-community.

Please upgrade to the lastest 5.1 or even better 5.5.10 !!!

In addition, always read release notes of MySQL versions before you install to see what bugs have been fixed (or what still needs fixing)

Comment: Thanks, will make the suggestion to our sys admin. I unfortunately don't have control over this :(